# Can click <s:TextInput> through a <s:label>

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, adobe, flex4.6

I'm trying to overlay a `<s:TextInput>` with a `<s:Label>`. The label should get visible=false on click. The problem is that when I click the label above the TextInput the TextInput get activated and the label click event is ignored.

I tried to adjust the depth setting but to no avail. I also tried to use `event.PreventDefault()` but it did not help either.

It almost seems like the label is transparent.

I cant figure this one out hopefully someone can help me.

**Update:**

This code shows the problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="HomeView">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:Label depth="1" width="200" backgroundColor="0xFFFFFF">
    Long boring text repeated a multiple of times. Long boring text repeated a multiple of times.Long boring text repeated a multiple of times. 
    </s:Label>
    <s:TextInput>

    </s:TextInput>

</s:View>
```

Comment: Maybe you can accomplish the same with the [prompt](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS19f279b149e7481c-177b1c712d80a315e7-8000.html) property?

Comment: You don't have to handle events of the both components to accomplish your issue. If your TextInput manages it's event in the right way and changes its visibility, you can just set the "visible" property of your label like this: visible = {!myTextInput.visible}

Comment: I agree with @splash: looks like you're trying to recreate functionality that's already built in.

Comment: I'm not sure if promt works. The texts that should are pretty lengthy and the textinputs are pretty close to each other. Thats why I need a label that covers the textinputs.

If something is written in the textinputs it shines through as well.

Comment: Seems very unergonomic to me, if one text shines through an other.

Comment: Defiantly. The application in not my doing in the first place and it is a patch work full of bad code. The customer wants to write novels in the box which makes it quite large. The box should pop up like a help box when the user clicks a icon. The promt property seems to be more like placeholder in html.

Comment: If you're still stuck, how about adding some code that represents the problem.

Comment: Updated the original question with a code example

Answer (score 0):

couple things, 1 since the text input is farther down in the mxml it is placed on top of the label. 2, components have properities like mouseEnabled, mouseEnabledWhereTransparent, childrenMouseEnabled, etc.  Try setting those to false on the component you don't want to be clickable, and in the event handler swapping which component is mouseEnabled.